# D3DImage and remote desktop

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, remote-desktop, direct3d11

I wrote an app that renders 3D content with D3D 11.0, and presents in WPF with [D3DImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage?view=netframework-4.8).

When the app is launched in a remote desktop session, after first couple of frames it receives [IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.isfrontbufferavailablechanged?view=netframework-4.8) event, [IsFrontBufferAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.isfrontbufferavailable?view=netframework-4.8) becomes false and stays this way.

For now, I’m detecting remote session and switching to the software rendering mode of D3DImage, that is I’m passing true to the last argument of [SetBackBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.setbackbuffer?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Interop_D3DImage_SetBackBuffer_System_Windows_Interop_D3DResourceType_System_IntPtr_System_Boolean_), ignoring IsFrontBufferAvailable being false, and rendering anyway.

It works but quite slow.

Both WPF, and my D3D11 rendering use hardware acceleration supported through RDP protocol. On my side I don’t use WARP devices or anything, just the normal `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE` with feature level 11.0 works fine, doesn’t even produce any messages from debug validation layer.

Is there a way to enable accelerated remote rendering for D3DImage as well?

Both client and server are running Windows 10 1903.

Comment: One option is to not use RDP, VNC and NoMachine allow running 3D accelerated applications as normal

Comment: @AlanBirtles That’s a good option. Unfortunately, my client is trying to use the app in Windows Server 2019 VM in Amazon AWS, GPU instances are significantly more expensive there.

Comment: Nothing to stop you installing VNC or NoMachine on AWS?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Lack of D3D11 GPU on the server. In the EULA of GPU drivers, nVidia forbids to use GeForce GPUs in data centers. Amazon has no other option but to pass the sky high cost of Tesla/Grid to customers.

Comment: Ah I see, you're trying to use the client's GPU on the server, that wasn't clear to me